# WCF and Data Transfer Object

Tags: wcf, dto, restsharp

I am stuck on this simple question. In my console application, I want to consume a wcf service. So I add the web reference to the project and call it. That is it.

But why I saw some examples especially using RESTSHARP, they never add web reference. They just use so called "DTO" to return object by the service and consume it.

I hope somebody can clarify the concepts for me. Is DTO used inside WCF?

sample:

```
private static List<ApplicationDTO> features;
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://" + baseUrl + "/FacilityData.svc");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.Resource = "/GetFeatures";
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("Id", 888);
var response = client.Execute(request);
features = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ApplicationDTO>>(response.Content);
```

Comment: I understood this concept using this link: [DTO & POCO](http://rlacovara.blogspot.com.es/2009/03/what-is-difference-between-dto-and-poco.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4b4f9665-d953-42e6-ac00-6fcde4380f92/) post:

> For REST service, it provides a generic way for WCF service consuming
>   which doesn't rely on the SOAP. **That's why we no longer need "Add
>   ServiceReference..." for consuming it.** REST service operations can be
>   accessed through standard HTTP GET/POST request, so any webrequest
>   enabled client can consume it. For example, you can use HttpWebRequest
>   to invoke a REST operation and use LINQ to XML to load and extract
>   values from the response XML data. It's very flexible.

DTO, usually used for Data Transfer Object - is nothing more then entity you want to pass as parameter / receive as a result.

In your example,  `ApplicationDTO` - is probably some entity to hold Data about Application Feature object (Name, Type, ...)

Comment: From the link you provided, can we say there are two ways to consume REST service? One is through HTTP GET/POST request, the other one is through factory-channel? About DTO, I still don't understand it, did you mean that was used in WCF to pass a parameter/entity?

Comment: Usually, yes - DTO is collection of data for your business object (Student, ClassRoom, ... And its not only about wcf, its used as "concept" (synonym for Entity, business object, ...)